# MySQL multiple condition Type

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm creating a CMS from scratch.
I'm looking for a way to set a value in my database following a specific condition.

The context here is I want to save records for the deleted or edited comments that would have been reported by the community.
Then I wanna view those logs/records but I have trouble defining wheter or not those values are **deleted** or **edited**.
( this is important to view the logs, obviously )

Here is the code i've done so far to **insert the logs**.

```
// Insert logs moderation
public function insertLogs($idCommentaire){
    $sql ="INSERT INTO logs(com_id, com_date, com_author, com_content, post_id) 
    SELECT com_id, com_date, com_author, com_content, post_id FROM 
    comments WHERE com_id = ?";
    $this->executeRequest($sql, array($idCommentaire));
}
```

Now I would like to set it up if it's **modified** or **deleted**, depending on which method I call this SQL, here is an example for the deletion :

```
$this->admin->insertLogs($idCommentaire);
$this->admin->suppressCom($idCommentaire);
```

I've created a new column ENUM from MySql ("deleted" "modified") but can't figure out how can I update this Logs table with the datas on it.

Here is the SQL I'm thinking about :

```
UPDATE logs SET type =("modified"OR"deleted") WHERE com_id = 70;
```

Note that it's not a good coding, just what I want to do in my mind.

I'm talking about plain MySQL here, if it's possible to combine it all in one request.
Otherwise I would set up 1 more request, 1 for each, but I don't know if it's really clean to do so.

What's your advices and thoughts about it ?
Thanks you all.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem. Are you currently looking for a database structure to give you the ability to know if a comment was edited or deleted or both ?

Comment: No, my database is already set I'm looking for any SQL statement that can fit my needs, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't too bad.  However, I'll note a couple of things.

1. `TYPE` is a reserved word in MySQL and probably most RDBMSs.  Pick
   another name for your column that indicates if a post has been
   modified or deleted.
2. There is at least one more state for a post; it's approved, or
       published, or 'okay', or whatever you'd like to call it.  So if you
       create an ENUM field called
       `SomethingOtherThanTypeThatStillMeansType`, or `foo` or
       `post_status` or whatever, include fields for all potential states
       your data may have, including *deleted*, *modified*, *posted*, *not_yet_posted*, *edited*, or whatever you think the system may support at the time of some future feature update.
3. You might consider using an `INT` type for your status field.  I'm
       thinking that might be a tad faster than an `ENUM`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Currently as I said my database has two tables for the comments.
Anything which goes from posted to "flag" the moderation is in the first one.
When it goes to the Log table, it is assumed the message is already moderated.

The way it is is and how can I store it is my whole question.
So right now I'm using two different SQL insertions, one for each.
I'm wondering if I can optimize it, as stated above.

For the whole 'ENUM' thing, yeah I was playing around it I admit , I should probably use INT and link it to another table which states the status. Thanks.